# Rotating, scaling and translating 2d points in GLM

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am currently trying to create a 2d game and I am a bit shocked that I can not find any transformations like rotation, scale, translate for vec2.

For example as far as I know rotate is only available for a mat4x4 and mat4x4 can only be multiplied by a vec4.

Is there any reason for that?

I want to calculate my vertices on the CPU

```
std::vector<glm::mat2> m;
```

Gather all matrices, generate the vertices, fill the GPU buffer and then draw everything in one draw call.

How would I do this in glm? Just use a mat4 and then ignore the z and w component?

Answer (score 7):

One thing that you should understand is that you can't just ignore the z component, let alone the w component. It depends on how you want to view the problem. The problem is that you want to use a mat2 and a vec2 for 2D, but alas it's not as simple as you may think. You are using OpenGL, and presumably it's with shaders too. You need to use at least a `glm::mat3`, or better: `mat4`. The reason for this is that although you want everything in 2D, it has to be done in terms of 3D. 2D is really just 3D with the z-buffer being 1 and the clip pane simply static, relative to the Window size.

So, what I suggest is this:

1. For your model matrix, you have it as a `glm::mat4` which contains all data, even if you don't intend to use it. Consistency is important here, especially for transformations.
2. Don't ignore the z and w component in `glm::mat4`; they are important because their values dictate where they are on screen. OpenGL needs to know where in the z-plane a value is. And for matrix multiplication, homogenous coordinates are required, so the w component is also important. In other words, you are virtually stuck with `glm::mat4`.
3. To get transformations for `glm::mat4` you should

   `#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>`

Treat your sprites separately; as in have a `Sprite` class, and group them outside that class. Don't do the grouping recursively as this leads to messy code. Generating vertices should be done on a per-Sprite basis; don't worry about optimisation because OpenGL takes care of that for you, let alone the compiler on the C++ side of things. You'll soon realise that by breaking down this problem you can have something like

```
std::vector<Sprite*> sprites;

for (const auto& : i)
    i->init();

// etc...

for (const auto& : i)
    i->render();
```

With regards to the shaders, you shouldn't really have them inside the Sprite class. Have a resource loader, and simply have each Sprite class retrieve the shader from that loader.

And most importantly: remember the order of transformations!

With regards to transformations of sprites, what you can do is have a `glm::vec3` for sprite positions, setting the z-component to 0. You can then move your sprite by simply having a function which wants x and y values. Feed these values into the model matrix using `glm::translate(..)`. With regards to rotation, you use `glm::rotate()` and simply have functions which get rotation angles. **ALWAYS ROTATE ON THE Z-PANE** thus it should be similar to this:

```
modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));
```

As for scaling, again a suitable `setScale()` function that accepts two values for x and y. Set the z component to 1 to prevent the Sprite from being scaled in z. Feed the values into `glm::scale` like so:

```
modelMatrix = glm::scale(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(scale));
```

Remember, that storing matrices provides little benefit because they're just numbers; they don't indicate what you really want to do with them. It's better for a `Sprite` class to encapsulate a matrix so that it's clear what they stand for.

You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I haven't looked hard enough:

[`GLM_GTX_matrix_transform_2d`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00209.html) from [`glm/gtx/matrix_transform_2d.hpp`](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.9.8/glm/gtx/matrix_transform_2d.hpp).